# Cannot access PHPUNIT_SELENIUM_TEST_ID cookie in PHPUnit Coverage

Tags: selenium, phpunit

To use `phpunit_coverage.php` I need to set `auto_prepend_file` and `auto_append_file` properties in `php.ini` to specified files `prepend.php` and `append.php`. In both scripts cookies are checked to make sure that test is running:

```
if ( isset($_COOKIE['PHPUNIT_SELENIUM_TEST_ID']) &&
```

The problem is that this cookie is kept as localhost's cookie, not the webserver's. So when it is checked, it is not set and xdebug doesn't start.

Selenium and webserver are located on different machines, could this be the cause of this error?

Situation is displayed here:

[image: firefox cookies manager]

Comment: I found out that problem is when I create cookie with `createCookie()` method, it is assigned to `localhost`, so I don't have any access to it after.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a work around for this?  I'm hitting it now.

Comment: @KarlZilles Have you tried Jérôme workaround? Unfortunately, this was a long time ago and I don't remember exactly how I've solved this problem. I don't have any access to this code now and I guess it has been changed after I had left that job. The only thing I remember is that I specified host in configuration, and possibly used it to set a cookie explicitly for a given host. Good luck with this!

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue. I thought at first of a domain problem as the tested web site is on a vhost.

But I found out that calling `$this->url('some_url')` seemed to silently delete the `PHPUNIT_SELENIUM_TEST_ID` cookie.

My workaround was overriding the `url()` method in my test cases, in order to reset the cookie once `url()` is called.

```
protected function url($url =null)
{
    try {
        $cookie = $this->cookie()->get('PHPUNIT_SELENIUM_TEST_ID');
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {}

    $result = parent::url($url);

    if (isset($cookie)) {
        $this->cookie()->add('PHPUNIT_SELENIUM_TEST_ID', $cookie)->set();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The code coverage files are now correctly created.